Python implementation of bellman equation in Merton Model
Simple code to find optimal allocation in year t between investing in stocks (X) vs prepaying mortgage (1-X) from simulated joint distribution of stocks and mortgage rates. Can't get the simulation on the Bellman equation to work...
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
START_MORTGAGE = 500000
INITIAL_EARNINGS = 220000
EARNINGS_GROWTH = 0.05
NON_MORTGAGE_SPENDING = 70000
SPENDING_GROWTH = 0.06
INITIAL_STOCKS = 60000
PROPERTY_VALUE = 650000
PROPERTY_GROWTH = 0.02
RISK_AVERSION = 2
DISCOUNT_RATE = 0.03
MORTGAGE_TERM = 25
SIMULATIONS = 1000
YEARS = 10

# Distribution parameters
STOCK_MEAN_RETURN = 0.09
STOCK_STD_DEV = 0.20
MORTGAGE_MEAN_RATE = 0.03
MORTGAGE_STD_DEV = 0.01
CORRELATION = 0.2

# Generate joint distribution
np.random.seed(42)
covariance = STOCK_STD_DEV * MORTGAGE_STD_DEV * CORRELATION
mean = [STOCK_MEAN_RETURN, MORTGAGE_MEAN_RATE]
cov = [[STOCK_STD_DEV**2, covariance], [covariance, MORTGAGE_STD_DEV**2]]
simulated_data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, (SIMULATIONS, YEARS))
stock_returns = simulated_data[:, :, 0]
mortgage_rates = simulated_data[:, :, 1]

def utility(wealth, gamma):
    """CRRA Utility Function."""
    if wealth <= 0:
        return -np.inf
    return (wealth ** (1 - gamma)) / (1 - gamma)

def calculate_excess_earnings(gross_income, tax, spending, mortgage_payment):
    """Calculate excess earnings."""
    return gross_income - tax - spending - mortgage_payment

def tax_calculation(gross_income):
    """Simple progressive tax calculation."""
    personal_allowance = 12570
    basic_rate = 50270
    higher_rate = 150000

    if gross_income <= personal_allowance:
        return 0
    elif gross_income <= basic_rate:
        return (gross_income - personal_allowance) * 0.2
    elif gross_income <= higher_rate:
        return (basic_rate - personal_allowance) * 0.2 + (gross_income - basic_rate) * 0.4
    else:
        return (basic_rate - personal_allowance) * 0.2 + (higher_rate - basic_rate) * 0.4 + (gross_income - higher_rate) * 0.45

def calculate_pmt(rate, term, principal):
    """Calculate the mortgage payment using the PMT formula."""
    if rate == 0:  # Handle zero interest rate case
        return principal / term
    return (rate * principal) / (1 - (1 + rate) ** -term)

def calculate_principal_payment(mortgage_payment, mortgage_rate, outstanding_mortgage):
    """Calculate the principal portion of the mortgage payment."""
    interest_payment = outstanding_mortgage * mortgage_rate
    return mortgage_payment - interest_payment

# Bellman Equation Implementation
def optimize_allocation():
    optimal_allocations = np.zeros((YEARS,))
    
    for sim in range(SIMULATIONS):
        mortgage = START_MORTGAGE
        stocks = INITIAL_STOCKS
        equity = PROPERTY_VALUE - mortgage
        property_value = PROPERTY_VALUE
        
        earnings = INITIAL_EARNINGS
        spending = NON_MORTGAGE_SPENDING
        
        for year in range(YEARS):
            stock_return = stock_returns[sim, year]
            mortgage_rate = mortgage_rates[sim, year]

            mortgage_payment = calculate_pmt(mortgage_rate, MORTGAGE_TERM, mortgage)
            tax = tax_calculation(earnings)
            excess_earnings = calculate_excess_earnings(earnings, tax, spending, mortgage_payment)
            principal_payment = calculate_principal_payment(mortgage_payment, mortgage_rate, mortgage)

            # Try different allocations to find the optimal one
            best_allocation = 0
            best_utility = -np.inf
            for x in np.linspace(0, 1, 101):  # Test allocations from 0 to 1 in increments of 0.01
                stocks_next = stocks * (1 + stock_return) + x * excess_earnings
                mortgage_next = max(mortgage - principal_payment - (1 - x) * excess_earnings, 0)
                property_value_next = property_value * (1 + PROPERTY_GROWTH)

                equity_next = property_value_next - mortgage_next
                wealth_next = equity_next + stocks_next

                discounted_utility = utility(wealth_next, RISK_AVERSION) / ((1 + DISCOUNT_RATE) ** year)

                if discounted_utility > best_utility:
                    best_utility = discounted_utility
                    best_allocation = x

            # Update values
            stocks = stocks * (1 + stock_return) + best_allocation * excess_earnings
            mortgage = max(mortgage - principal_payment - (1 - best_allocation) * excess_earnings, 0)
            property_value = property_value * (1 + PROPERTY_GROWTH)
            
            optimal_allocations[year] += best_allocation
            
            # Update income and spending for next year
            earnings *= (1 + EARNINGS_GROWTH)
            spending *= (1 + SPENDING_GROWTH)

    # Average the optimal allocations across simulations
    optimal_allocations /= SIMULATIONS

    return optimal_allocations

# Run optimization
optimal_allocations = optimize_allocation()

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(range(1, YEARS + 1), optimal_allocations, marker='o')
plt.title("Optimal Stock Allocation Over Time")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Fraction of Excess Earnings Allocated to Stocks")
plt.grid()
plt.show()


It would be useful if you could show exactly the model you are trying to solve.
In any case, solving a Bellman equation problem by monte carlo is a terrible idea. You would need a waaaay larger simulation.
You want to solve the belman equation first and then simulate the model.
You need to approximate returns (look at Tauchen-Hussey approximation), and then solve the bellman by backward induction. Should be a trivial process I can sketch it but will need a better view of the problem you are trying to solve.

I am trying to find the optimal allocation each year over 10-year period of excess earnings into stocks X vs mortgage repayment (1-X) that max sum U(Wt) / (1+ discount rate) ^ t). The 10-year annual stock returns and mortgage rates are drawn from a joint distribution; U(W) = (1 - W^(1 - R)) / (R - 1) using risk aversion of 2; Equity = property value – outstanding mortgage; W = equity + stocks; Excess earnings = gross earnings - tax - mortgage cost - other spending. Perhaps a different approach is warranted to resolve this?
